# publishing multiple apps into 1 Cloud Foudry environment /instance

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am using Java 7/Spring Boot 1.3.2 (with embedded TC 8) and Cloud Foundry.  When I published 2 apps into 1 CF node using manifest.yml, I noticed something strange.
Here is the setup:
Environment:
    2 Spring Boot apps (uses Spring boot plug-in in Gradle to build 2 executable jars) that have embedded Tomcat 7 and expose 2 unique set of REST services.  I see both apps in the CF dashboard as published successfully.

Test:
  As soon as app A is published (and app B is being published) run appA's corresponding REST client.  This is successful

As soon as App B is published, run appB's corresponding REST client.  This is successful

Run the 2 tests above and I noticed that the web server that's fronting the 2 apps is now load balancing between appA and appB.  So this causes every other client call to fail if you alternate between appA and appB clients.

So the question is Should I add "no_route" token to the manifest if I dont want the load balancing?
What effect will this have when I have multiple instances of appA or appB in CF?

My manifest.yml:

```
---
applications:
  - name: appA
    host: myCloud
    buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
    path: ./build/libs/appA-myCloud-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    memory: 512M    
    instances: 1    
  - name:   appB
    host: bclCloud
    buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
    path: ./build/libs/appB-myCloud-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    memory: 512M    
    instances: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest.yml file, you have `host: mycloud` and `host: bclCloud`. If your default CF domain is, say, `mycf.example.com`, then the apps should be available with URLs `mycloud.mycf.example.com` and `bclCloud.mycf.example.com`. CF sees these as unique routes to two different apps, and will not load balance between the two.

You can run `cf apps` after pushing these apps and look at the `urls` column of the output to make sure that each app is getting a unique route.

> I noticed that the web server that's fronting the 2 apps

What web server are you referring to? The CF Router is the only CF component in front of the apps, and it won't load balance between two unique apps.

Comment: thx for the comment. This is exactly what I was wondering was happening.  I changed the hosts to be unique and the CF router was able to route properly.  I am a novice at this and still trying keep my head above the water.  The web server that I am referring to the CF router (still trying to get to the correct terminology).